# PHP html_entity_decode not converting slash

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm using PHP 7.4 and running into a strange problem. I have some variables coming in from a GET request, looking like this:

`start_date=12%2F1%2F2020&end_date=12%2F31%2F2020`

I decoded the GET request into two variables, `$start_date` and `$end_date`.

I then ran `html_entity_decode($start_date, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`, but my string is still `12%2F1%2F2020` instead of what I expect: `12/1/2020`.

I also ran it without any arguments, ie. without ENT_COMPAT, and my result is still the same.

Am I misunderstanding what `html_entity_decode` does? I could just do a `str_replace` but I'm trying to do this the right way.

Comment: [You must be looking for `urldecode`.](https://3v4l.org/74D5g)

Comment: This should be in the $_GET array: array (
  'start_date' => "12/1/2020",
  'end_date' => "12/31/2020",
). Where do you get the above data from?

Comment: Like you said, you're apparently misunderstanding. HTML entities are those ampersand+semicolon things like &nbsp;, &copy;, &aring;, etc.. That's not the same thing as URL coding. You can try `parse_str(urldecode('start_date=12%2F1%2F2020&end_date=12%2F31%2F2020'), $result); print_r($result);` if you'd like an example :).

Answer (score 0):

html_entity_decode() is the wrong function. urldecode() is also not required, because [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) does that with (See Note in the PHP Manual).

```
$queryString = 'start_date=12%2F1%2F2020&end_date=12%2F31%2F2020';
parse_str($queryString, $getArray);
var_dump($getArray);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["start_date"]=>
  string(9) "12/1/2020"
  ["end_date"]=>
  string(10) "12/31/2020"
}
```

If the string comes from $_SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'] then [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is also not necessary because the result is already in $_GET.